# Multiplying binomial with absolute values

Tags: complex-numbers, absolute-value

I am inexperienced with math and I need help with absolute values and complex numbers.

Given the following:
$$
|a||b|=|ab|
$$

Assuming $a$ and $b$ are real, is the following statement true?
$$
(|a|+|b|)|a+b|=|a||a+b|+|b||a+b|=|a(a+b)|+|b(a+b)|=|a^2+ab|+|b^2+ab|
$$

How can this be simplified?

How about the complex case (say $a=re^{i\phi}$ and $b=se^{i\theta}$)?

Edit: I am trying to prove the following:
$$
|a+b|\ge\frac{1}{2}(|a|+|b|)\left|\frac{a}{|b|}+\frac{b}{|b|}\right|
$$

I have gotten this far but am stuck:
$$
2|a+b|\ge\left|r\left(1+e^{i(\theta+\phi)}\right)\right|+\left|s\left(1+e^{i(\theta+\phi)}\right)\right|
$$

I would ask this as a separate question but math.stackexchange is prohibiting me from doing so because I am a new user and prohibited from asking more than 2 questions within 48 hours.

Comment: All your steps are correct. The absolute value plays well with multiplication.

Comment: Looks ok at first glance. Why don't you try justifying each equality? e.g. The first equality follows from distributivity: $(a+b)c = ac + bc$

Comment: the equation is true, even for complex case.  the proof is tedious, mechanical and straightforward.  what do you mean by "simplified"?  for me, the expanded and factorized forms are quite simple